# How can I run cronJob after every 31 second?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I want to run cronjob after every 31 seconds but it always runs twice in a minute like when the minute begins and after 31 seconds.

**Output of my code:**

```
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:58:00 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:58:31 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:59:00 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:59:31 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 18:00:00 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 18:00:31 GMT
```

But I want to run it after 31 seconds.

**What I'm expecting:**
`

```
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:58:00 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:58:31 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:59:02 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 17:59:33 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 18:00:04 GMT
Sat, 21 Jan 2023 18:00:35 GMT
```

**Here is the Code:**

```
const { CronJob } = require('cron')
new CronJob(
    '*/31 * * * * *',
    () => console.log(new Date().toUTCString()),
    null,
    true,
    'UTC'
)
```

`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The reason I'm asking - wanting to setup the cronjob like you described doesn't look like the end goal, but rather a method of getting something else done, which would make it an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/339067).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
31 * * ? * *
```

It means every minute at 31 seconds

Comment: No, Actually I want to run the cron after 31 seconds as my first cron ran on 31 seconds then the second cron should run on 62 seconds (add 31 seconds).

Comment: I think this is not possible just with cron expression. It's a scheduler, and I think you can't use it this way.

You can use the setInterval function with that with the timeout of 31 seconds